# android camera flash black picture

Tags: android, flash, android-camera

I am using android camera api,when the flash is active the result picture is black .
I tried the following:
I put the camrea near the wall and i see white picture.
I checked with the default camera and the flash is working.

```
Parameters params = cameraObject.getParameters();
params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
cameraObject.setParameters(params);
```